# How to evaluate "Header" and "Payload" in Gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to call a POST method which needs both header and body.

**RequestGateway.java**

```
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;    
import java.util.Map;

public interface RequestGateway {

//  Using this throws error
//  This complains saying no more than one Payload parameter
//  String process(Map<String, String> request, String x, String s);

    String process(@Payload Map<String, String> request, @Header("accountReferenceId") String x, @Header("profileReferenceId") String s);

}
```

**Java Class**

```
public void test(String accountReferenceId, String profileReferenceId) {
.....
.....
        RequestGateway paymentRequestGateway = context.getBean("paymentRequestGateway", RequestGateway.class);
        String paymentResponse = paymentRequestGateway.process(paymentRequestMap, accountReferenceId, profileReferenceId );
}
```

**SIConfig.xml**

```
<!--HEADER MAPPER-->
<bean id="headerMapper"
      class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Api-Key, Accept, Content-Type" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>

<int:gateway id="paymentRequestGateway"
             service-interface="com.abc.api.payments.inboundpayments.api.RequestGateway"
             default-request-channel="PaymentRequestChannel"
             default-reply-channel="ResponseChannel">
    <int:default-header name="Accept" value="application/json; v=5"/>
    <int:default-header name="Content-Type" value="application/json; v=5"/>
    <int:default-header name="accountReferenceId" expression="#args[1]"/>
    <int:default-header name="profileReferenceId" value="test"/>
</int:gateway>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="Payment Outbound Gateway"
        request-channel="PaymentRequestChannel"
        reply-channel="ResponseChannel"
        error-handler="errorHandler"
        request-factory="sslFactory"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        url="https://localhost:9090/accounts/{accountReferenceId}/payments?profileReferenceId={profileReferenceId}"
        http-method="POST"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        extract-request-payload="true">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="accountReferenceId" expression="headers['accountReferenceId']" />
    <int-http:uri-variable name="profileReferenceId" expression="headers['profileReferenceId']" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

In the default header **expression="#args[1]"** is not getting evaluated properly. When I put value directly such as `<int:default-header name="accountReferenceId" value="test"/>`, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong with the expressions here?

Comment: How is it evaluated then? I have just tested it locally and works well. Even with similar ` @Header("accountReferenceId") /  <int:default-header name="accountReferenceId" >` mix. Please, explain your aim: how it should be. What do you expect to see?

Comment: Hi Artem, If I call `test(abc, def);` the url-expression in the default header should be evaluated as `https://localhost:9090/accounts/abc/payments?profileReferenceId=def`, doesn't seem to be happening like that coz it works when I give direct values. I am not sure how this is being evaluated currently, perhaps I should set the log level to debug?

Comment: Well, that looks like some mix. You don't show the method with *two args*... Right, it would be good to configure DEBUG for `org.springframework.integration` to see how the `headers` looks. From other side it would be better to debug SI code from your side directly. Or even more better to come up with some simple test-case to reproduce from our side.

Comment: The method `test(String accountReferenceId, String profileReferenceId)` in my code is in fact a REST controller method, and even though I was encoding the values and invoking this controller method, the encoding was being stripped off and so I had to re-encode this value using `accountReferenceId = URLEncoder.encode(accountReferenceId, "UTF-8");` in my method body, and now it works fine :). Thank you for quickly testing it out for me and giving confidence that my Spring Integration code is fine. Spent hours to solve this mystery. If you would like to answer this question, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to switch on the `DEBUG` for the framework category and see what's going on with executions.

In our case it is `org.springframework.integration` and with the debug you can see in the logs something like:

```
QueueChannel: (main) preSend on channel 'channel', message: GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@17f6480: startup date [Fri Feb 05 18:36:32 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy], headers={id=8e832449-cc71-bd19-45d2-a396d553cdd5, timestamp=1454715393215}]
```

With that in hand you can parse your own headers, determine the channel and try to figure out who is guilty.

Plus keep in mind that Spring Integration provides [`Message History`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history) pattern implementation, where with the logs you are able to `trace` the message journey.